# Convex hull of all co-linear points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, convex-hull

This is pretty trivial, but still I wanted to know what would be the convex hull if the points are characterized by line x = y i.e. all points are co-linear.Would that be the same case as 2 points i.e. the line segment joining all the points

Comment: The two farthest endpoints would be the only points constituting the convex hull.

Comment: @Cyber, erm not quite. The convex hull would be the line segment spanning the two farthest points.

Comment: Well... yeah. Do as I mean, not as I say :)

Comment: @SchighSchagh but if I am to list all the points in the hull what should i do, just two end points or all

Comment: The convex hull of co-linear but distinct points contains an infinite number of points, so I'm not sure what you are asking by saying that you are "to list all the points".

Comment: We are given say 20 points like (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 3)... now out of these how many should i list? All?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally the convex hull of a set of points is computed and outputted as the convex hull of the vertices (since this is the same as the convex hull of the original set of points, but it is a smaller and non-redundant description). So, traditionally to compute a convex hull, you compute the vertices of the convex hull and then say you are done. If all your points lie on a line, then there are only two vertices: The two extreme endpoints along the line. Thus traditionally you would represent the convex hull by saying that it is the convex hull of these two extreme points (the two vertices), which is the line segment connecting the two vertices by definition of convex hull.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), Convex Hull is the "smallest convex set that contains X". If that convex set is a polygon, it may be represented by the points in its vertices. But **it isn't the points**.

So, what should you output depends on how the problem requests you to represent the convex hull. Usually you will only have to output the two farthest points, but some problems may accept colinear points in the answer.

As an exercise, think that the convex hull may not be a polygon:

[image: convex hull]